# I can't get a sprite to draw to the screen

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a Flappy Bird game entirely in HTML and JS.

I can't get the medals to show up on-screen. No matter where I try to draw them, they don't show up at all. These medals are the only sprites that won't show up, and I used the same structure as every other sprite in the game.

```
function Sprite(img, x, y, width, height) {
this.img = img;
this.x = x * 2;
this.y = y * 2;
this.width = width * 2;
this.height = height * 2;
};
Sprite.prototype.draw = function(ctx, x, y) {
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height,
    x, y, this.width, this.height);
};
```

That's where the .draw() is initialized.

```
if (currentstate === states.Score) {
    s_text.GameOver.draw(ctx, width2 - s_text.GameOver.width/2, height - 400);
    s_score.draw(ctx, width2 - s_score.width/2, height - 340);
    s_buttons.Ok.draw(ctx, okbtn.x, okbtn.y);

    s_numberS.draw(ctx, width2-47, height - 304, score, null, 10);
    s_numberS.draw(ctx, width2-47, height - 262, best, null, 10);

    switch (score) {
        case > 50 :
            s_medals.gold.draw(ctx, 73, 181);
            break;
        case > 20 :
            s_medals.silver.draw(ctx, 73, 181);
            break;
        case >  5 :
            s_medals.bronze.draw(ctx, 73, 181);
            break;
    }

}
```

That's where it's drawn

Any debugging help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: You guys definitely had a point with that. Apologies.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your post.

Comment: Please include a minimal working example of code that reproduces your issue. No way would I download and open a random ZIP file from the interwebs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can't expect us to sift through your entire project, re-writing it for you. If you could include just the relevant code (how you draw the sprites on screen, and the code for the coin sprites themselves) we will be more able to help you.

Comment: Please include your source code in the question.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please include your source code in the question.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Open your dev console (F12 in most browsers) and set a test of your vars for validity in Sprite.prototype.draw: `console.log(this.img.width,this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);` Then ask yourself if the img.width>0 (meaning the image has been loaded) & ask yourself whether the other values correctly describe the position of your sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the help guys, but I figured out what was wrong. On the spritesheet I was using, the medal wasn't being selected properly, so nothing showed up. It was still being drawn.